# Освещение OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, освещение

Что не так с моим освещением? Вроде все нормально, но на деле не то что нужно.

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI  3.1415
#endif
float winWid = 600.0;
float winHeig = 600.0;
float angleX = 90, angleY = 0;
float scale= 1.0;
int          button = -1;
float        mouseX, mouseY;

float mat1_dif[]={0.8f,0.8f,0.0f};            
float mat1_amb[] = {0.2f,0.2f,0.2f}; 
float mat1_spec[] = {0.6f,0.6f,0.6f};
float mat1_shininess=0.5f*128; 

float mat4_dif[] = {0.9f,0.2f,0.9f};
float mat4_amb[] = {0.2f,0.2f,0.2f};
float mat4_spec[] = {0.6f,0.6f,0.6f};
float mat4_shininess = 0.1f*128;
GLuint texture;

GLuint LoadTextureRAW( const char * filename, int wrap )
{
    GLuint texture;
    int width, height;
    unsigned char * data;
    FILE * file;

    // open texture data
    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

    // allocate buffer
    width = 256;
    height = 256;
    data = (unsigned char*) malloc( width * height * 3 );

    // read texture data
    fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
    fclose( file );

    // allocate a texture name
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

    // select our current texture
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    // select modulate to mix texture with color for shading
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

    // when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                 GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
    // when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first mipmap
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    // if wrap is true, the texture wraps over at the edges (repeat)
    //       ... false, the texture ends at the edges (clamp)
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                  wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                 wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );

    // build our texture mipmaps
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,
                   GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

    // free buffer
    free( data );
    return texture;
}
void cube(float size){
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_AMBIENT,mat4_amb);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,mat4_dif);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,mat4_spec);
glMaterialf(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,mat4_shininess);
glutSolidCube(size);
}

 void torus(float innerRadius, float outerRadius, GLint nsides, GLint rings){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_AMBIENT,mat4_amb);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,mat4_dif);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,mat4_spec);
   glMaterialf(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,mat4_shininess);
   glPushMatrix();// запис поточної матриці в стек
   glutSolidTorus (innerRadius, outerRadius, 40, 40);
   glPopMatrix();
   }

void lines(double x, double y, double z){
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(int i=x-winWid/2; i<winWid/2;i+=10){
        glVertex2f(i, -winHeig/2);
        glVertex2f(i, winHeig/2);
    }
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(int i=y-winHeig/2; i<winHeig/2;i+=10){
        glVertex2f(-winWid/2, i);
        glVertex2f(winWid/2, i);
    }
glEnd();
}

void on_keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
switch(key){
    case 'r':
        angleX=90;
        angleY=0;
        scale=1;
    break;
    case 'a' : 
        if(angleX==360){
            angleX=0;
        }
       angleX++; 
    break;
    case 'd' : 
        angleX--; 
    break;
    case 'w' : 
        if(angleY==360){
            angleY=0;
        }
       angleY++; 
    break;
    case 's' : 
        angleY--; 
    break;
    case 'q' :
        if(scale<5)
            scale+=0.1; 
    break;
    case 'e' : 
        if(scale>1)
        scale-=0.1; 
    break;
  }
 }

 void on_specKeyboard(int key, int x, int y){
switch(key){
    case GLUT_KEY_F1:
        angleX=90;
        angleY=0;
        scale=1;
    break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT : 
       angleX++;
    break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT : 
        angleX--;
    break;
     case GLUT_KEY_UP : 
       angleY++;
    break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN : 
        angleY--; 
    break;
}
}

 void on_paint(){
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glClearColor(0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angleX, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glRotatef(angleY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glScalef(scale, scale,1.0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glRotatef(90,0,1,0);
        glTranslatef(0,0,-150);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-200.0, -200.0);
            glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(200.0, -200.0);
            glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(200.0, 200.0);
            glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-200.0, 200.0);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-120, -75, -80);
    glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
        torus(15,10,20,20);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-120,-75,80);
    glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
        torus(15,10,20,20);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-120,75,-80);
    glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
        torus(15,10,20,20);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-120, 75,80);
    glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
        torus(15,10,20,20);
    glPopMatrix();


    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

 void initialize(){
 glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
 glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
 glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glOrtho( -winWid/2, winWid/2, -winHeig/2, winHeig/2, -200, 200);

  }


void on_mousePressed(int _button, int state, int x, int y){
 if (state == 1) {    // 0 - натиснули на кнопку, 1 - відпустили кнопку
 button = -1;      // ніяка кнопка не натиснута
 return;
 }
  switch(button = _button){
  case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON:
    angleX=90;
    angleY=0;
    scale=1;
    break;
 case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if(scale<5)
        scale+=0.1;
    break;
 case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
    if(scale>1)
        scale-=0.1;
    break;
 }
}
void on_mousePressedMove(int x, int y){
 switch (button) {
 case 0:
   angleX += x - mouseX;
   angleY += y - mouseY;
   mouseX = x;
   mouseY = y;
   break;
  }
}


void on_timer(int value)
{
   on_paint();                     // перемалюємо екран
   glutTimerFunc(75, on_timer, 0); // через 33мс викличеться ця функція
}

float ambient[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
float diffuse[] = {0.3,0.9,0.67,1.0};
float specular[] = {0.45,0.50,1.0,1.0};
float position[] = {50.0,50.0,50.0,0.0};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //Инициализация
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(winWid, winHeig);
    glutCreateWindow("Test 1");
    //Регистрация
    initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(on_paint);
    glutKeyboardFunc(on_keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(on_specKeyboard);
    glutMotionFunc(on_mousePressedMove);
    glutMouseFunc(on_mousePressed);
    glutTimerFunc(75, on_timer, 0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: С освещением всё в порядке. Есть источник света, он освещает.

Comment: Покажите, чем "все нормально" отличается от "не то что нужно"?

Comment: Функции glMaterialfv ожидают вектор из 4 float, а вы передаёте только 3. Может быть у вас в прозрачности мусор?